# Сериализация массива в XML в Android

Tags: android, xml

В `Android`-приложении создаю `XML` подобным образом:

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();  

        Element Date = document.createElement("Data");//одиночный элемент
        rootElement.appendChild(Date);
        Date.appendChild(document.createTextNode(dateAdd));

        for (int i=0; i<edtList.size();i++)
        {
            Element stringsElement = document.createElement("strings");
            rootElement.appendChild(stringsElement);
            Element itemGroupId = document.createElement("itemGroupId");
            stringsElement.appendChild(itemGroupId);
        }
```

В итоге получаю такую `XML`:

```
<Data>08-04-2017</Data>
    <strings>
        <itemGroupId>051304008778</itemGroupId>
    </strings>
    <strings>
        <itemGroupId>051304008778</itemGroupId>
    </strings>
```

Что надо сделать, чтобы данные сериализовались в следующем формате, т.е. все элементы массива - `<strings>`, которые отправляются в `XML` были "обернуты" одним общим тегом - в данном случае `<Lines>`:

```
<Data>08-04-2017</Data>
<Lines>
    <strings>
        <itemGroupId>051304008778</itemGroupId>
    </strings>
    <strings>
        <itemGroupId>051304008778</itemGroupId>
    </strings>
</Lines>
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавить элемент `Lines` точно так же как Вы это сделали для `Data` (хотя, может, логичнее было бы назвать `Date`).

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();  

Element date = document.createElement("Data");   //одиночный элемент
rootElement.appendChild(date);
date.appendChild(document.createTextNode(dateAdd));

Element lines = document.createElement("Lines"); //контейнер
rootElement.appendChild(lines);

for (int i=0; i<edtList.size();i++)
{
    Element stringsElement = document.createElement("strings");
    // здесь элемент добавляется внутрь lines, а не rootElement
    lines.appendChild(stringsElement);
    Element itemGroupId = document.createElement("itemGroupId");
    stringsElement.appendChild(itemGroupId);
}
```